# making a window unusable when new window opens with Tcl/Tk

Tags: user-interface, window, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm building a GUI using Tk/Tcl. during the use I create a new window which has some properties in it for the user to fill up. I want that my main window will be unusable during all time that the properties window is not closed, and only when it's closed to bring back the option to use the main window.

How do I do it?

I create the new window using `toplevel .prop_menu`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`grab`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grab.htm). See also http://wiki.tcl.tk/grab and http://wiki.tcl.tk/3326

Comment: by using `grab release .top; grab set .prop_menu;' I was able to "block" the main window, and when I exit the properties window using `grab set .top` returns control to it.

Comment: @Ilya: Your program should not normally be holding any grabs; when you exit the properties window you should `grab release .prop_menu` or just `destroy .prop_menu` (which will drop the grab if held). OTOH, it's usually better in a modern GUI to not be using modal dialogs at all.